# How to enable PHP Session?

Tags: php, html, forms, wordpress, session

I need a contact form linked in WordPress to work which is generated by a software. According to the customer support PHP Sessions should be enabled which will get the form to work. However I've already tried doing that in this tutorial:

http://support.qualityunit.com/021373-How-To-Enable-Session-Support-for-PHP

Although there are some parts which I do not understand in this tutorial such as:

```
**session.save_path = "C:\php\sessiondata\"** - *Why is it drive C if the website is live? What would be the correct file path?*
```

and the last part which says:

"There are some more setting which may be used to modify your Sessions. For more  Details refer php.ini
support manually in each page script:
 **Call session_start() function.**"

Other than that tutorial, is there a more elaborate way to enable PHP sessions?

**By the way, I am using PHP 5.3**

AND the error that I receive when trying to fill in the contact form is this:

**Your form could not be submitted for the following reason(s):

```
Warning: [ err 2/line 366/config.cls.php] session_start(): open(/var/php_sessions/sess_88f8205d8a552c001940ab1c2780b949, O_RDWR) failed: No such file or directory (2)**
```

Comment: Keep it in the tmp folder.  Otherwise you have to give the webserver permissions to that folder, becomes a pain sometimes.

Comment: @wes thanks for your reply. How do I set the file path for that? I'm pretty noob at setting up these kind of things. Do you set this in the php.ini? Thanks again!

Answer (score 4):

To the best of my understanding, you simply need to call `session_start()` at the top of each page you would like to use session variables on.

Answer (score 2):

put that first to all in the page

```
<?php
    session_start();
?>
```